# Javascript: Changing properties if screen is turned do not work on Samsung. Ideas how to fix that?

Tags: javascript, android, screen-orientation, samsung-mobile

Ho Guys i have this little code which changes my width if i rotate my phone.

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {

  if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {

document.getElementById("iframe-startpage-mobile").style.width ="90%";
document.getElementById("iframe-startpage-mobile").style.marginLeft ="5%";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("iframe-startpage-mobile").style.width ="100%";
        document.getElementById("iframe-startpage-mobile").style.marginLeft ="0%";
    }

  }, false);
```

It works perfect on my Android Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 (works in chrome and firefox) but it dosn´t work on my Samsung Galaxy S8 ( not chrome or samsung browser). Any idea how i can fix that?

Comment: Are you really sure about the tags of this question?

Comment: ups not java thx

Comment: better i guess :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use wordpress and on my samsung galaxy in landscape mode wordpress ( i use the avada fusion template ) think that the galaxy screen is an medium screen. So i just toggle the container on medium screen too and now it works :) The Problem was my galaxy showed me the container for dekstop which has another id so i thaught my nothing happend but this was wrong it just dosn´t happend on my mobile-container. I simply changed #iframe-startpage-mobile to #iframe-startpage evethings fixed. Thx for the attention :D

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong exactly? Is the `orientationchange` event not firing, or the `matchMedia` query returns the wrong result?

I have no chance to test on a Samsung phone but some general workarounds:

### orientationchange

You could replace it with `window.onresize`. Just be careful not to do heavy work on that handler (or at least apply something like a *debounce* to it), it is invoked constantly while resizing.

### matchMedia

You could achieve similar results via something along the lines of:

```
function is_landscape() {
   return (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight);
}
```

Comment: the event is not firing i try your code and bring back soem results thx :D

Comment: tried everything it works on all phones just not on my s8 ;/